# What causes "Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.2.3" in bundler?

Tags: ruby, bundler

In my Gemfile, I have

```
ruby '>= 2.2.3'
```

and my Ruby version is 2.2.3

```
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified >= 2.2.3
```

2.2.3 is greater than or equal to 2.2.3, so what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using an old version of bundler (1.10.6), which unlike the [current](http://bundler.io/gemfile_ruby.html) version [didn't support](http://bundler.io/v1.10/gemfile_ruby.html) operators like `>=` with regards to Ruby itself (as opposed to gems).